# Why would a MySQL function be getting randomly dropped?

Tags: mysql

I have the following function that is used in several databases on my server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_strings_intersect`(arg_str1 VARCHAR(255), arg_str2 VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    SET arg_str1 = CONCAT(arg_str1, ",");
    SET @var_result = "";

    WHILE(INSTR(arg_str1, ",") > 0)
    DO
        SET @var_val = SUBSTRING_INDEX(arg_str1, ",", 1);
        SET arg_str1 = SUBSTRING(arg_str1, INSTR(arg_str1, ",") + 1);

        IF(FIND_IN_SET(replace(@var_val, ' ', ''), arg_str2) > 0)
        THEN
            SET @var_result = CONCAT(@var_result, @var_val, ",");
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    IF (@var_result = "")
    THEN
      RETURN false;
    ELSE
      RETURN true;
    END IF;
END;
```

Periodically, and in no predictable manner, the function is getting dropped across all databases.

Is there something about the function or possibly my MySQL configuration that would/could cause this function get get dropped?

Comment: Is it the only one that’s getting dropped? Have you tried making a dummy function with the same name but different contents or the same contents but different name? Have you checked which databases use it or other functions call it to see if one of those could be causing it?

Comment: Its the only function I have.  Is there anything about the name that would suggest it as the cause of the problem?  I'm inclined to say its not the code that is calling it that is causing the problem because every function for every database is getting dropped at the same time.  Code on one site wouldn't have access to drop anything on another site.

Comment: I don’t see anything obviously suspicious, but that’s why I suggested trying dummy functions. If a function with the same contents but different name gets dropped, then you know there’s something about the contents and you can try removing parts of it to narrow down exactly what is triggering the problem. If a dummy function with the same name but different contents gets dropped, then something is dropping it by name. Is the actual function exactly as above or does it include comments?

Comment: Exactly as above.

Comment: Are you restoring a backup of the mysql database periodically ??

Comment: No.  We are doing a nightly dump but that doesn't appear to be affecting it since its happening randomly and never anywhere near when the nightly dump takes place.

Comment: Could it be that the function causes an exception? The random part would be some weird parameters you have not foreseen. You might add an error handler.

Comment: Would MySQL drop a function if it caused an exception?

Comment: I don't know, but as the function looks harmless, a problem during execution might be the reason for the problem.

Comment: The OP says, “It’s the only function I have.” Also (apparently) a function with the same contents but different name also gets dropped. @DarrellBrogdon: have you tried a dummy function with _different_ contents (e.g., none) and a different name? Perhaps the problem is that ***any*** function gets dropped.

Comment: @Scott I'll try that.  I haven't tried a different function name with the same contents yet.

Comment: If the test of an empty function with same name does not show this problem, this may possibly indicate that a problem during execution is actually the cause.

Answer (score 4):

By any chance, are you using --skip-grant-tables on your daemon startup?

From the documentation for CREATE FUNCTION

> An active function is one that has been loaded with CREATE FUNCTION and not removed with DROP FUNCTION. All active functions are reloaded each time the server starts, **unless you start mysqld with the --skip-grant-tables option**.

Comment: It doesn't appear that mysql was started with that switch: `mysql     6428  0.5 14.2 1382020 293176 ?      Ssl   2013 154:25 /usr/sbin/mysqld`  This is on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with stock MySQL I believe.  So unless the stock MySQL on Ubuntu comes with --skip-grant-tables it shouldn't have that flag enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The function seems harmless enough at first sight, but I do wonder what would happen if
it caused an exception during execution.
I don't know MySQL well-enough to predict what it will do -
for all I know it might drop or disable the function.

The random part for when this happens would be some weird and rare parameters
that you have not foreseen that cause the exception.

You could test an empty function with same name.
If this function does not show the problem, this may possibly indicate that
there exists a run-time problem.

A second test would be to add an error handler to the function to see if the problem
will then disappear.